# How to draw a sinewave in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am an absolute newbie in LaTeX in general and Tikz in particular and am in the process of exploring various aspects of the ecosystem. During the course of looking Tikz related information I came across this response: [Sinewave in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78407/30520).

This works but I am unable to figure out how this works. Can someone point me or explain how these commands combine to generate a sine wave?

Comment: Good Q: But to what `frequency` and `amplitude` you wish to know is another Q due to `phase` difference of learning :) I am sure [`texdoc tikz`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) would be too exhaustive may be start with http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/TikZ.pdf and Related Links at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz

Comment: I must say, this SE site is the friendliest of the lot. This question has been received amazingly. Thanks.

Comment: Someone downvoted, can he\she please explain why?

Comment: Once any one edits the Q for [eg: due to the current edit here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/162648/2) anyone after the edit of Q they can retract their upvotes/downvotes. So someone would have taken back their upvotes since i see no downvotes on your Q

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Last Error has given the snippet from manual and there shouldn't be any *error* anymore. But still some illustration would be nice. This answer serves that purpose.

Let use consider the construct:

```
\draw[ultra thick, red] (3,0) sin (4,1)
```

in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
    \draw (0.2,1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=1$} -- (11.8,1);
    \draw (0.2,-1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=-1$} -- (11.8,-1); 
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,12}{
    \draw (\x,-0.2)node [below,font=\tiny,] {\x} -- (\x,0.2) ;
    }
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (3,0) sin (4,1);    %% the real business in this line
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It says that starting from the point `(3,0)` draw a `sin`e curve and end the curve at the point `(4,1)`:

[image]

Please note that the `sin` and `cos` commands draw only a quarter sine/cos curve  and the `y` coordinate of two points should be different. For example, if you draw

```
(3,0) sin (11,0)     %%% same y-coordinate
```

you will get a straight line like:

[image]

Now add the line

```
\draw[ultra thick, blue] (4,1) cos (5,0);    %% the real business in this line
```

This says that start a `cos`ine curve at `(4,1)` and end it at `(5,0)`:

[image]

The blue curve is the cosine curve. You add `sin` and `cos` curves like this continuously and alternatively to get a continuous sine wave:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
    \draw (0.2,1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=1$} -- (11.8,1);
    \draw (0.2,-1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=-1$} -- (11.8,-1); 
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,12}{
    \draw (\x,-0.2)node [below,font=\tiny,] {\x} -- (\x,0.2) ;
    }
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (3,0) sin (4,1);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (4,1) cos (5,0);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (5,0) sin (6,-1);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (6,-1) cos (7,0);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (7,0)  sin (8,1);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (8,1) cos (9,0);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (9,0) sin (10,-1);    %% the real business in this line
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (10,-1) cos (11,0);    %% the real business in this line
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All `red` curves are sine curves and the `blue` ones are cosines. Instead of putting many separate `\draw` commands like this, you can stuff all of them in one `\draw` command:

```
\draw[ultra thick, red]
    (3,0) sin (4,1) cos (5,0) sin (6,-1) cos (7,0)
          sin (8,1) cos (9,0) sin (10,-1) cos (11,0);
```

as Peter Grill did in his linked answer

Comment: The expository aspects of this answer trump the other one. I'll wait for some time, and accept this one. Also, this was a question was born out of curiosity, not out of an error.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520385/201329

Answer (score 33):

According to Karl's students (who don't care about almost everything in TikZ) on page 30 of TikZ documentation (by invoking `texdoc tikz` in your terminal, shell, DOS prompt), they said that

[image]

### Sine

Remember 3 important behaviors:

- `sin (x,y)` draws only the first 1/4 of a complete sine curve. In other words, the curve in the first quadrant is drawn.
- the previous point is used as the starting point.
- if the previous point is lower than `(x,y)` then it draws sine with positive amplitude. Otherwise it draws with negative amplitude.

If you still get confused with these 3 rules, the progressive examples as follows should help you understand its behavior.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2) sin (3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2) sin (3,5) sin (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

### Cosine

Cosine is the "complement" of sine. The following examples should make it clearer.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) cos (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2) sin (3,5);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) cos (1,2) cos (3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2) sin (3,5) sin (5,0);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) cos (1,2) cos (3,5) cos (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

### Summary

If you want to create a complete sine wave then you need to use both `sin` and `cos` alternately as follows,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,-3) grid (5,3);
    \draw[green] (0,0) sin (1,2) cos (2,0) sin (3,-2) cos (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

because using `sin` alone does not produce what you want to get as follows.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,-3) grid (5,3);
    \draw[red] (0,0) sin (1,2) sin (2,0) sin (3,-2) sin (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: why does your sine shake/break is it resolution problems

Comment: @texenthusiast: No. It is not about resolution but by design feature of `sin` and `cos` implemented by TikZ.

Comment: I keep my tutorial above as simple as possible because in my experience reading complicated code just increases confusion.