# Trouble drawing a sine curve in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a sine function going out from a particular point. When I use {sin(x r)} it gives kinked lines. When I use this code I get a lot of errors that say "Package pgf Error No shape named (0 is known.
Package TikZ Error Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

Here is my code:

```
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 16} 
 \draw ((0.05+\x), (3.1+{sin(((pi*\x)/4) r)})) to [out=90*\x, in=(90*(1+\x))] ((0.5+(\x+1)*.25), ({sin((pi*(\x+1)/4) r)}+3.1));
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! You need to be careful with the parentheses and add multiplication signs `*` and braces where appropriate. Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,16} 
{\draw ({0.05+\x},{3.1+sin(pi*\x/4 r)}) 
to [out=90*\x, in=90+90*\x] 
({{0.5+0.25*(\x+1)}}, {sin(pi*(\x+1/4) r)+3.1});}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. There is no error but the output suggests you may have had something different in mind.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162648/how-to-draw-a-sinewave-in-tikz/162654#162654