# Draw a sine wave below an image using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a sine wave below an image. Following is the code I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\tikzset{
    % Tikz style used to work in relative coordinates to the underlying picture
    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Import picture and select it as bounding box
\node[use as bounding box]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\linewidth]{Figure.png}};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
\draw[red, domain = 0.128:0.961] plot [smooth] (\x,{0.1 * sin(\x * pi/0.5 r)});

% Grid lines
% \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
% \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=south] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
% \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=west] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

As apparent from the image, I am not able to get one complete cycle of the sine wave. I tried different with inputs for the draw command i.e.,

```
\draw[red, domain = 0.128:0.961] plot [smooth] (\x,{0.1 * sin(\x * pi/0.5 r)});
```

**Desired output**

I want to plot one complete cycle of sine wave between `x = 0.0` and `x = 1.0` in the image. Also, I want to shift this sine wave to `y = -0.1`. Is this possible? The image without the sine wave can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI51b.png).

Furthermore, is there any function in `TikZ` that takes the `wavelength` and `amplitude` as input and produces a `sine` wave? If yes, this will be very helpful as it provides a general solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't also draw the axes instead of importing them as an external image?

Comment: Will you please post code that can be compiled. And what is that `r` in `{0.1 * sin(\x * pi/0.5 r)}`?

Comment: @JuanCastaño, I want to draw sine wave on a plot of a some data. The image I shared is the reduced version of the actual image.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The code above compiles. Regarding `r` I am not completely sure. I think it stands for radians. That line of code is borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78447/203675).

Comment: I understand now. Then perhaps the solution posted by Skillmon is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Original answer

Your issue why you don't get a complete sine is that you have some padding from the used `\node`. You should use `inner sep=0pt` in the options of that node to get the correct bounding box coordinates for your sine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\tikzset{
    % Tikz style used to work in relative coordinates to the underlying picture
    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Import picture and select it as bounding box
\node[use as bounding box,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\linewidth]{example-image-duck}};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
\draw[red, domain = 0:1] plot [smooth] (\x,{0.1 * sin(\x * pi/0.5 r)});

% Grid lines
% \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
% \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=south] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
% \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=west] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## New answer

By extensive trial and error the following uses a two step approach to position your sine.

First we find two points in your image by using coordinates relative to the image (so that this still works if you resize your image, but only for this one image, happy extensive trial and error for any other image), the points we search for are (0,0) and (1,1). I called these `(bl)` for *b*ottom *l*eft and `(tr)` for *t*op *r*ight.

Then we change coordinates yet again to use the two found points as reference. Now we can use your images coordinate axis in that scope and simply draw your sine there by using `plot`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\tikzset{
    % Tikz style used to work in relative coordinates to the underlying picture
    % (slightly altered)
    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947
    use node coordinates/.style={
      shift={(#1.south west)},
      x={(#1.south east)},
      y={(#1.north west)}
    },
    use two point coordinates/.style 2 args={
      shift={(#1)},
      x={(#1-|#2)},
      y={(#1|-#2)},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Import picture and select it as bounding box
  \node[inner sep=0pt](img){\includegraphics[width = 0.4\linewidth]{sinewave.png}};
  \begin{scope}[use node coordinates=img]
    \coordinate(bl) at(0.0715,0.0833);
    \coordinate(tr) at(0.958,0.948);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[use two point coordinates={bl}{tr}]
    \draw[red, domain = 0:1] plot [smooth] (\x,{0.1 * sin(\x * pi/0.5 r)-0.1});
    % Grid lines
    % \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    % \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=south] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    % \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=west] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Skillmon, I think there might a misinterpretation of the question. I want the wavelength of the sine wave to be less than the length of the image as the wavelength should be equal to the length of the x-axis (I have shared the image in the question). Furthermore, is it also possible to shift the sine wave to `y = -0.1`?

Comment: @Aim then I have the same question as already asked in the comments: Why don't you draw the canvas in Ti*k*Z. Why do you use an external graphic in the first place?

Comment: @Aim See the edit. But note that I don't think this is a viable solution you should use more than once. The extensive trial and error is really no fun.

Comment: @ Skillmon The external image is generated using a python script. Hence, I have no choice other than importing it.